# ASP.NET page lifecycle - between constructor and Page_PreInit (the "start stage")

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

There are plenty of articles that explain the [ASP.NET WebForms page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), but what happens between the constructor in the code-behind page getting called and the `Page_PreInit` event? MSDN refers to this time as the "start stage" of the page.

I am debugging some code in which there is often a moderate delay between these two events (determined using logging, delay of the order of a few seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods of the Page class that are called before the PreInit event is fired. Maybe one of those is responsible for the delay. See the following illustration, which is on the same page you included in your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations.

Answer (score -2):

the first called function is Constructor.(obviously...)

after this other event will raised.